# Chrome in windows table column width not as defined or consistent between browser versions

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, browser

I'm having an issue on the table column width. It only happens on windows surface chrome. (v55 latest version at this moment)

Running the code below in (zoom 100%):

- Windows surface chrome: the width of the column is 27.33px for t2
- Other browsers: the width of the column is 27px for t2

How can I prevent this? Is it a browser bug?

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-spacing: 0;
  text-align: center;
}

.t1 td {
  width: 108px;
}

.t2 td {
  width: 27px;
}

td {
  white-space: nowrap;
  border: 2px solid red;
}
```

```html
<table class='t1'>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>4</td>
  </tr>
</table>

<table class='t2'>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>4</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: How do you know the width?

Comment: by inspecting the element using chrome DevTools

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some time investigating, it seems like a chrome specific bug.

https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=377847

Cant find any hack/solution to make it work. For my specific use case, to resolve the problem, i decided not to use table.